# Python not importing files when not inside conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I am importing class from a file inside the folder source.

source --> file.py

```
from source.file import *
```

But the import does not work when I am outside conda environment. Why so?

Comment: Because the relevant package is only installed inside the conda environment?

Comment: which package? source and file.py are custom made

Comment: And you are inside the parent directory when running Python? Do you use a script that has the import, or do you use the Python prompt?

Comment: `import *` is bad practice.

Comment: I agree that, I was using a code written by another guy :D

Answer (score 2):

Your Conda environment may use a different, newer, interpreter, which doesn't require `__init__.py` files for a directory to be a package. To have it work outside the Conda environment, add an empty `__init__.py` file inside the `source` folder.

That would be the case if Conda uses Python 3.3+, while outside of Conda your Python executable defaults to a lower version, e.g., Python 2 (which is really out of date now, and should not be used anymore).